# Type of redux action using ownProps in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have this action in my slice:

```js
setTimerState(state, { payload }: PayloadAction<{ timer: StepTimer, timerState: CookingTimerState }>) {
  const { timer, timerState } = payload
  state.stepTimers
    .find(t => t.timerId === timer.timerId)!
    .state = timerState
}
```

I've written my `mapDispatch` action so that I can call it very simply in my component:

```js
type Props = {
  timer: StepTimer
  startTimer?: any // FIXME
};

const StepTimerComponent = ({ timer, startTimer }: Props) =>
  <StepTimerButton onClick={ startTimer }>
    { timer.label }  
  </StepTimerButton>

const actions = (dispatch: AppDispatch, { timer }: Props) => ({
  startTimer: () => dispatch(setTimerState({ timer, timerState: CookingTimerState.Running }))
})

const StepTimerContainer = connect(null, actions)(StepTimerComponent)
export default StepTimerContainer
```

This works fine, but the type of `Props` is bothering me. What should it actually be?

1. It's currently optional. If I take out the `?` to make it non-optional, I get a TS error from the calling component:

```
Property 'startTimer' is missing in type '{ timer: StepTimer; key: number; }' but required in type 'Props'.  TS2741
    13 |     timers.length ? timers.map((timer, i) =>
  > 14 |       <StepTimerContainer timer={ timer } key={ i }/>
       |        ^
    15 |     ) : "No timers."
```

But doesn't the `connect` function supply that prop to the wrapped component?

2. `startTimer: any` what should it actually be??? I've tried a number of permutations and they get errors either from the `onClick` type, or more importantly from the `connect` call's final argument. For example `startTimer: PayloadAction<{timer: StepTimer, timerState: CookingTimerState}>` gets both those errors. (and then trying `onClick={ () => startTimer() }` says that `startTimer` is not callable.

**What's the correct type for `startTimer`?**

Comment: Just use `useDispatch`, it doesn't affect the props and allows you to not have to worry about the type (unless you are using thunks, in which case there's information about how to type that correctly in the description for it.

Comment: I want to keep my components ignorant of redux (which will be clearer once the container component and the presentation component are in separate files) so I don't want to use any redux hooks in the component itself. Although I guess I could rewrite the container components using the hooks?